# How do I animate a set of UIImages backward inside UIImageVIew - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, imageview, uiimage

I have an array of UIImages and I'm trying to animate it in a particular way. Just like the instagram boomerang feature.

When the animation arrives to the last frame It goes backward and arrives to the first and the process continues.

What I've been doing till now has been this:

```
imageView.animationImages = [myImages]
imageView.animationDuration = 0.9
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2
imageView.image = imageView.animationImages?.first
imageView.startAnimating()
```

How can I achieve that boomerang Loop if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest we override the `startAnimating()` method. This way we can provide our own logic of the animation and decide what the next frame should be.

We'll create a `frameTimer` that will replace the image of the UIImageView every equal fraction of the `animationDuration`. It'll iterate over the images array forwards and backwards until stopped with the `stopAnimating()` method.

```swift
class BoomerangImageView: UIImageView {
    // MARK: Overrides
    override func startAnimating() {
        guard let frames = animationImages, frames.count > 1 else {
            return
        }
        image = frames.first
        
        let timePerFrame = animationDuration / Double(frames.count)
        let timer = Timer(fire: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: timePerFrame),
                          interval: timePerFrame,
                          repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.changeFrame()
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
        frameTimer = timer
    }
    
    override func stopAnimating() {
        frameTimer?.invalidate()
        frameTimer = nil
        currentFrameIndex = 0
    }
    
    // MARK: Private
    private var frameTimer: Timer?
    private var isAnimatingForward = true
    
    private var currentFrameIndex = 0 {
        didSet {
            if let frames = animationImages,
               currentFrameIndex >= 0,
               currentFrameIndex < frames.count {
                image = frames[currentFrameIndex]
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func changeFrame() {
        guard let frames = animationImages, frames.count > 1 else {
            stopAnimating()
            return
        }
        
        let canAnimateForward = currentFrameIndex < frames.count - 1
        let canAnimateBackward = currentFrameIndex > 0
        isAnimatingForward = (isAnimatingForward && canAnimateForward) || (!isAnimatingForward && !canAnimateBackward)
        currentFrameIndex += isAnimatingForward ? 1 : -1
    }
}
```

Then in your view controller, you run the animation just like you planned:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: BoomerangImageView!
    
    let frames: [UIImage] = [
        // your images here
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageView.animationImages = frames
        imageView.animationDuration = 2
        imageView.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

It should look something like this:

[image: boomerang demo]

Comment: Thank you, when I finish work I'll try it and let you know if it works!

Comment: It works perfectly! thank you very much @Anton Barkov

Comment: Nice, glad to help!